# How can I successfully lock down node module dependencies in a monorepo?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, lerna

I'm working on an open source project which is currently using [lerna](https://lernajs.io) to help manage a single repository with multiple packages. So far, so good, except that every now and then something breaks because we don't currently shrinkwrap anything. I've been trying to do some monorepo version of shrinkwrapping so that we're not at the mercy of all our dependencies (it's amazing how often everything goes wrong in the middle of a release!) but have hit a bit of a wall and wondered if I'm even on the right track.

I was originally hoping to use npm shrinkwrap which I was familiar with from previous projects. Unfortunately [lerna doesn't appear to support shrinkwrap](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/377).

Plan B was to make use of yarn which, after some initial difficulties, seemed to be going ok after switching to using yarn workspaces- at least I think `yarn install --frozen-lockfile` was doing what I wanted.

Unfortunately, other than dependency locking, yarn doesn't seem to be helping- everything worked with npm and lerna, but lerna and yarn workspaces seems to be causing issues resolving modules (even resolving something in the same directory which is baffling).

Maybe switching to yarn is overkill anyway so I started wondering if more recent versions of npm and **package-lock.json** would be a better idea. Unfortunately that looks like it [would need some work arounds with lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/938) at which point I'm beginning to wonder how much lerna is really adding. Maybe [dropping lerna](https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/457cdb309c9ec5b39f0d420266a9faa4) would help?

So, *tl;dr*, does anyone have a good way of locking down module dependencies in a monorepo?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest simply using exact versioning; so in your `package.json` files where there are version numbers for dependencies like `^3.4.2`, changing it to `3.4.2`. The `^` (or `~`) before the number suggest a version range. You can get that to happen with the [save exact config option](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-exact): `--save-exact` flag or by placing `save-exact=true` in a `.npmrc` file in the repo. `lerna add` also supports an [exact option](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/add#--exact).

Hope that helps!

Comment: That is indeed the work-around we used, unfortunately it's only marginally better since it's unlikely that all your dependencies will specify exact versions of their dependencies. The closest I got to an answer was with Rush - https://rushjs.io - unfortunately I ended up working on other things so I wasn't able to migrate the old project over to confirm it did actually work. It looked promising though and I'd be keen to try it out for any future mono repos.

Answer (score 0):

`yarn` is a production ready package manager that natively supports monorepos :)

When using `yarn workspaces`, there is no need to use `lerna` as a monorepo manager as well at the same time.

You can use other features of lerna if you want, but there is no reason to use lerna for installing monorepos (which are already uses yarn).

If there is a specific errors when installing/managing monorepo using `yarn`, please add them to the question.

Notes:

- `--frozen-lockfile` doesn't do anything in yarn monorepo. `yarn` has a open issue on that which I think won't resolve soon.

Comment: I'm guessing yarn has changed a bit since 2017 but problems with `--frozen-lockfile` don't sound reassuring.

So far [Rush](https://rushjs.io/) seems to be working ok with this monorepo -> https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-node